# How to Configure all MachineToApplication settings in your application's root?

Tags: asp.net

`Default allowDefinition='MachineToApplication'`

I have been looking around on different sites and fora, and i have a similar problem than some people had before... it is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplicat

How to use this solution:

Configure all MachineToApplication settings in your application's root,
and remove all MachineToApplication settings from your application's
subdirectories.

Comment: From dictionary.com a subject means "The theme of a sermon, book, story, etc"

Comment: How about posting your web.config then we might have a chance at pointing you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

That means if you have any web.config files in you subdirectories, remove the MachineToApplication section.

However, this problem is usually indicative of something else.

Can you post the entire stack trace?